# Member function pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, pointers

In A.h:

```
class A 
{
    typedef void (A::*fp)();
    void test1();
    void test2();
    A(int a);
}
```

In A.cpp I have:

```
A::A(int a)
{
    fp fpointers[] = {&A::test1,&A::test2};

    fpointers[a]();
}
void A::test1()
{
//do something
}
void A::test2()
{
//do something
}
```

This is a reduced and simplified version of what I have. But the problem is still valid. From my humble experience 'fpointers' is how you define and declare an array of function pointers. I am having problem with line `fpointers[a]();`I am getting this error:

> expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have
>   (pointer-to-) function type

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah, will fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Off topic: [Take a look at `std::function`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) Bit more runtime overhead, but cleans up some of the messiness of method pointer syntax. Especially interesting with [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks, will do :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax would be

```
(this->*fpointers[a])();
```

as you need instance.